# how can I reposition patterns within a string using sed?

Tags: regex, sed, bioinformatics

I have a fasta file of +20k intronic sequences with the following headers I can describe as:

```
>ENSG[0-9] | ENST[0-9] | start_position | end_position | name |
```

I would like to change positions of ENSG[0-9] and ENST[0-9] and add "NASCENT" to ENST[0-9] pattern.

I tried:

```
sed 's/\(ENSG\d*\) *| *\(ENST\d*\) */\2 | \1/'
```

to first just focus on repositioning, but to no avail. It's probably escapes that I've confused.

Any hint or a better solution?

Comment: please show a [mcve] so we can play with it

Comment: Your regexp does not take the square brackets into account.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I think the header description already is meant as some kind of pattern, but it's not quite clear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I got your input format correct but if an example file would like this:

```
>ENSG1 | ENST1 | 1 | 3 | name1 |
ATG
>ENSG2 | ENST2 | 4 | 9 | name2 |
ATGATG
>ENSG12 | ENST12 | 10 | 17 | name12 |
ATGATGATG
```

calling sed with the following parameters:

```
sed 's/\(ENSG[0-9]\+\).*\(ENST[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)/NASCENT_\2 | \1\3/g'
```

would give you

```
>NASCENT_ENST1 | ENSG1 | 1 | 3 | name1 |
ATG
>NASCENT_ENST2 | ENSG2 | 4 | 9 | name2 |
ATGATG
>NASCENT_ENST12 | ENSG12 | 10 | 17 | name12 |
ATGATGATG
```